# sending multidimensional array via ajax, index[0] problems

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to send a multidimensional array from php to Javascript/jQuery but I'm having a problem.

When I'm sending index 0 via `json_encode($array);`, the client receives the response in the format I want:

```
[[0,0],[1,0.031410759078128],[2,0.062790519529313],[3,0.094108313318514].etc..]
```

When I inspect with firebug, the index 0 array sent doesn't seem to arrive with JSON?

When I send any other index of the array, the client receives the array in this format(which I don't want):

```
{"1":[1,0.031410759078128],"2":[2,0.062790519529313],"3":[3,0.094108313318514].etc..}
```

when I inspect the arrays received by the client when the index is anything other than 0, I can clearly see that it was sent using JSON.

What's the problem, and how can I get all of my indexed arrays sent using the same format as my array[0] ?

Here's my php code:

```
$strJEncoded = json_encode($array);
echo $strJEncoded;
```

Here's my JS/Jquery code:

```
$res = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
```

Comment: That second format is not a JSON array. It's an object with numeric keys whose values are themselves arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `json_encode()` will only produce a JSON array if the array indexes are sequential numbers starting from `0`. Otherwise, it produces a JSON object.

You can use `array_values()` to return an array with the indexes renumbered from `0`.

```
$strJEncoded = json_encode(array_values($array));
```

Comment: Thank you, my client receives the correct array format now!

Comment: @D4v3 you should accept check this answer if this did solve your problem